# Was Childhood's End Intended To Parallel Biblical Prophecy?

Tags: analysis, childhoods-end

I just finished watching the three-part SyFy channel mini-series adaptation of *"[Childhood's End](http://www.syfy.com/childhoodsend)"*, and I was left wondering about a number of seeming correlations between the story told ([originally by Arthur C. Clarke](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Childhood%27s_End)) and the Biblical prophecies of the "End Times".

Specifically, the character of Karellen seems to echo the Christian "[Antichrist](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Antichrist)" figure in a number of ways - not to mention

> his physical resemblance to the commonly used image for Satan and/or other demons.

Additionally,

> the removal of the children with the adults being left behind

is similar to the idea of the [Rapture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rapture) in [Christian eschatology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Christian_eschatology).

So, my question is, does anyone have any references to anything that would either confirm or deny an intended parallel between the story of *"Childhood's End"* (either in Clarke's original telling, or this new adaptation) and Biblical prophecy?